# Broadcast intents not working?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, manifest

I have been following TheNewBoston tutorials on Broadcast intents, but I have an issue. Basically, I have two apps:

1) Recieve Broadcast

2)Send_Broadcast.

They do what their name suggests using intents, and Recieve Broadcast responds to the broadcast by displaying a toast on the screen. At this point of time, I have built both apps, and am getting no errors. After running both though, nothing happens when I send the broadcast by pushing the button. Please help me with this issue, as I have been trying to fix this for almost two hours now! (I have also re-set the api from 8-14)

This is the java class for send broadcast, it sends the broadcast when you push this button:

[image: Send]

This is the XML for send broadcast, it sends the broadcast when you push this button:

[image: Send XML]

Here is the receiver:

[image: Reciever]

And the manifest which filters out certain broadcasts:

[image: Manifest]

I have not added a layout to recieve broadcast, it works behind the scenes. Thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it. If you need more information, feel free to ask!

I would appreciate **any** feedback! :)

Comment: in your manifest file. The intent filter needs to be within the broadcast receiver tag.

Comment: @Hades Thanks, that works! Is there any way to call the receiver from the send broadcast? Right now, I have to run each one separately, right?

Comment: @Hades Also, there is no way to run the receiver from my phone anyway, and the only way to make this app work is to plug-in to cpu and run both through android-studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intend to put your filter on your receiver?

```
    <receiver android:name=".RecieveBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.xxx.send_broadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it!

Comment: Cool. For future questions, please post text rather than images. It's typically easier for all parties.

Comment: I have a question. In order for this app to run, I need to run both apps one by one. Is there a way that I can run both apps at once in the sendBroadcast application?

Comment: You mean you want them to be in the same project?

Comment: Sort of... I want one project to call the other project whenever it is run. Is that possible? Thanks